# Is there a way to print in Python that will not output the current contents of stdin?

Tags: python

I'm using select to wait for stdin or data from the server/client, but if I receive a message while typing, my current text is printed as well the received message. I may be using select incorrectly, but I need to find a way to maintain what's currently being typed without it being output with the message.

Comment: show us the code

Comment: @TheBuffED I've proposed a possible solution but I'm not too sure if this is really what you need. If not tell me and I'll delete the post.

Comment: @armatita Thank you, I'll try it out when I get a chance

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it (so I might be a bit out of my expertise) but [RPyC](http://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) might be able to do what you are asking. In its [How To](http://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/howto.html) page they show a couple of snippets that direction the print for both host and local:

```
>>> import rpyc
>>> c = rpyc.classic.connect("localhost")
>>> c.execute("print 'hi there'")   # this will print on the host
>>> import sys
>>> c.modules.sys.stdout = sys.stdout
>>> c.execute("print 'hi here'")   # now this will be redirected here
hi here
```

, or:

```
>>> c.execute("print 'hi there'")                   # printed on the server
>>>
>>> with rpyc.classic.redirected_stdio(c):
...     c.execute("print 'hi here'")                # printed on the client
...
hi here
>>> c.execute("print 'hi there again'")             # printed on the server
>>>
```